# problem with appTrackingTransparency requestTrackingPermissionsAsync() returns true before user fills popup

Tags: expo

I have recently upgraded our apps to expo sdk 47 and I'm having the following problem with the lib 'expo-tracking-transparency'. The library allows us to display a pop-up prompting the user to inform us whether they accept or not that their activity be sent to other websites. The pop up shows as excepted in the app and the answer of the user is taken into account as it should. But before the user fills the pop up form, the library returns a default response of "true" (as if the user had already accepted the tracking).
Here is the code inside my main component :

```
const [isTrackingPermissionGranted, setIsTrackingPermissionGranted] = useState(false);

    // Request tracking permission (mandatory for iOS 14+)
    // Permission is automatically granted for iOS 13 and below and Android
    useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      const { granted } = await requestTrackingPermissionsAsync();
      console.log('GRANTED AFTER FILLING THE POPUP', granted);
      setIsTrackingPermissionGranted(granted)
    })()
  }, [])
```

At first the value of 'isTrackingPermissionsGranted" is false as expected. But then and even before the user has had time to fill up the pop up form, the variable returns true, as shown by my console log in the use effect.

Did anyone encounter a similar problem ? The fact that the variable becomes "true" as if of its own accord and if only for a brief moment has consequences on our website and what we display to the user.

Expected behavior : only set isPermissionsGranted to true if the user has exlicitally given their consent and filled the pop up form.